# Three.js cube transparent texture display edges

Tags: three.js, transparency, cube, texture-mapping, invisible

I'm trying to create the limits of the world in a game demo with three.js so I have created two cubes, each cube displays a "transparent forest texture" that will simulate the world limits.

My original problem was that the texture was displayed in all the faces of the cube but I wanted it to be displayed only in 4 of the faces.

**[UPDATED: I have managed to make the texture in the top face of the cube invisible but I can still see some kind of edges (I'm not sure about about what is it...) flying in the sky. The question is now how to hide the cube edges?]**

[image]

A closer look:

[image]

If you visit https://googledrive.com/host/0BynsKHbZoT73elJpaUxqTlprVjQ/demos/3dworld/ you will be able to see it in action.

My code is **[UPDATED]**:

```
    function createWall(texture,distanceFromMapLimit,wallsHeight,positiony){
        //texture
        var backgroundInteriorTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(texture,distanceFromMapLimit);
        backgroundInteriorTexture.wrapS = backgroundInteriorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        backgroundInteriorTexture.repeat.set( 10, 1 ); //repeat texture 10 times per face
        backgroundInteriorTexture.needsUpdate = true;
        // materials (for each face of the cube we will add one material)
        var backgroundInteriorMaterials = [];
        for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ) {
            if((i == 0) || (i == 1) || (i == 4) || (i == 5)) // side faces
            {
                console.log(i,'visible')
                backgroundInteriorMaterials.push(
                    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
                    {
                        map: backgroundInteriorTexture,
                        transparent: true,
                        opacity: 1, //visible
                        side: THREE.BackSide
                    }
                ));
            }
            else //top and bottom faces
            {
                console.log(i,'NOT visible')
                backgroundInteriorMaterials.push(
                    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
                    {
                        map: backgroundInteriorTexture,
                        transparent: true,
                        opacity: 0, //not visible
                        side: THREE.BackSide
                    }
                ));
            }
        }
        //geometry
        var backgroundInteriorGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(
            world.worldWidth + distanceFromMapLimit,
            wallsHeight,
            world.worldDepth + distanceFromMapLimit
        );
        //mesh
        var backgroundInteriorMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
            backgroundInteriorGeometry,
            new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(backgroundInteriorMaterials)
        );
        backgroundInteriorMesh.position.y = positiony;
        game.scene.add(backgroundInteriorMesh);
    }

    function createBackground(){
        //INTERIOR
        var wallsHeight = 4056;
        var positiony = 1750;
        createWall("Back_01.png", 0, wallsHeight, positiony); //just in ground limits
        //EXTERIOR
        createWall("Back_02.png", 5000, wallsHeight, positiony); //5000 away from ground limits
    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: As I had read the question before the edits and after, it does not make sense now. It is a totally different question with the wrong title.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot to update the title, The question is now how to hide the cube edges? thanks for your help